# New list based on 3 other lists

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, lambda

Starting with a CSV file with the columns `['race_number', 'number_of_horses_bet_on','odds']`
I would like to add/calculate an extra column called `'desired_output'`.

The `'desired_output'` column is computed by

- for 'race_number' 1, the 'number_of_horses_bet_on'=2, therefore in the `'desired_output column'`, only the first 2 `'odds'` are included. The remaining values for `'race_number'` 1 are 0. Then we go to `'race_number'` 2 and the cycle repeats.

[image]

Code I have tried includes:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv('test.csv')

desired_output=[]
count=0
for i in df.number_of_horses_bet_on:
    for j in df.odds:
        if count<i:
            desired_output.append(j)
            count+=1
        else:
            desired_output.append(0)
print(desired_output)
```

and also

```
df['desired_output']=df.odds.apply(lambda x: x if count<number_of_horses_bet_on else 0)
```

Neither of these give the output of the column 'desired_output'

I realise the 'count' in the lambda above is misplaced - but hopefully you can see what I am after.
Thanks.

Comment: Show the result your code generated please

Comment: Next time try to provide the used dataset as text instead of pictures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm gonna do it a bit differently, this will be what I'm gonna do

- get a list of all `race_number`
- for each `race_number`, extract the `number_of_horses_bet_on`
- create a list that contains 1 or 0, where we would have `number_of_horses_bet_on` number of 1s and the rest would be zero.
- multiple this list with the `odds` column

```py
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv('test.csv')

mask = []
races = df['race_number'].unique().tolist() # unique list of all races
for race in races:
    # filter the dataframe by the race number
    df_race = df[df['race_number'] == race]
    # assuming number of horses is unique for every race, we extract it here
    number_of_horses = df_race['number_of_horses_bet_on'].iloc[0]
    # this mask will contain a list of 1s and 0s, for example for race 1 it'll be [1,1,0,0,0]
    mask = mask + [1] * number_of_horses + [0] * (len(df_race) - number_of_horses)

df['mask'] = mask
df['desired_output'] = df['mask'] * df['odds']
del df['mask']

print(df)
```

> This assumes that for each race the numbers_of_horses_bet_on equals or less than the number of rows for that race, otherwise you might need to use min/max to get proper results

Comment: Thanks Jimmar - that works 100%. Trying to understand the line:                                      
mask = mask + [1] * number_of_horses + [0] * (len(df_race) - number_of_horses)       ......the [1] and [0] refer to the index position in a list - is that right?

Comment: oh, in python if you do for example `[2] * 3` you'll get [2,2,2]

Comment: you are welcome, if this answers your question then consider marking it as the correct answer